# How to throttle server events?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have an angular 6 app that communicates through a websocket, more precisely sockjs, with the server.
I start a task with the server, REST call, and I get a very large number of messages on the websocket.
The way my code is working is horrible. It essentially locks the screen as long as there are websocket messages are coming.

My current code is component

```
this.scenarioRunnerService.liveUpdate$
.subscribe(response => {
    this.processLiveUpdates(response.payload);
})
```

service code is

```
StompClientKeeper.getInstance().get()
.subscribe('/topic/abcd',
    (response: Response) => broadcast the new message);
```

How can I change this not to freeze the client?

Comment: The answer depends upon whether or not you want a lossy solution. Do you want to ignore some messages or not?

Comment: I can ignore any of them

Comment: And the `subscribe` hints that this could involve RxJS. Does it?

Comment: not following your comment, just looking for a way to avoid the application locking up

Comment: Is the `subscribe` call in the snippet because `liveUpdate$` is an RxJS observable? The question is not tagged as `rxjs`.

Comment: Oh I see your question, I will add rxjs tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to simply ignore some messages when they arrive too quickly, the [`auditTime`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/auditTime) operator is likely what you are looking for:

```
import { auditTime } from "rxjs/operators";

this.scenarioRunnerService.liveUpdate$.pipe(
  auditTime(400)
).subscribe(response => {
  this.processLiveUpdates(response.payload);
});
```

If multiple messages are received within the specified duration, `auditTime` operator will ignore all but the last-received message.

Alternatively, you could use the [`throttleTime`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime) operator. It's behaviour differs in that it will pass the first received message and will throttle subsequent messages that are received within the specified duration.

And the [`sampleTime`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/sampleTime) operator is another possibility. It's different again, as it would sample the received messages at the specified period.

Which operator you choose depends upon the behaviour that you want.

Comment: I will try the sampleTime, I think that is the most adequate one for my case. Thank you.